# trigger an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(this.element).live('mouseleave', function(evt){
$(this.element).trigger("mouseup");
});
```

I am trying to trigger mouseup event of same element on it's mouseleave but it's not working fine ,can anyone please suggest me the require change

Comment: Don't use `live` it is deprecated.

Comment: Please elaborate on the 'not working fine' part.

Comment: `this.element` ? Paste the HTML mark-up too...

Comment: Whilst I agree with live being deprecated ... you don't know what version of jQuery the user2123421 is using, so I ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

You're changing context when you handle the event.

try:

```
$(this.element).live('mouseleave', function(evt){
 $(this).trigger("mouseup");
});
```

This probably isn't the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve though - it's hard to tell without a wider code example.

You could declare you're own handlers and then call the handlers that wrap each event - that's probably a better solution!

## EDIT

In response to comment:

You could do something like this:

```
var myOnMouseUp = function(event){
  console.log('Do something on mouse up')
}

$(this.element).live('mouseleave', myOnMouseUp);

$(this.element).live('mouseup', myOnMouseUp);
```

Comment: I am not able to to understand " declare you're own handlers and then call the handlers that wrap each event" what exactly

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
$("#test").on("mouseup",function(){
alert("Mouse up triggered!");
});
$("#test").on('mouseleave', function(evt){
$("#test").trigger("mouseup");
});
```

where "test" is just a link.

http://jsfiddle.net/8D26W/